# Unable to install AWS CLI using CloudFormation UserData in RHEL

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to install `AWS CLI` in a `RHEL AMI` using `CloudFormation` `UserData`, this is what I tried:

```
"PublicInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-b55a51cc",
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "PublicInstanceType"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaces": [{
                "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false",
                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                "GroupSet": [{
                "Ref": "PublicSecurityGroup"
                }
                ],
                "SubnetId": {
                    "Ref": "PublicSubnet"
                }
            }],
            "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior": "stop",
            "Monitoring": "false",
            "Tenancy": "default",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
                "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                "Ebs": {
                "VolumeType": "io1",
                "Iops": "200",
                "DeleteOnTermination": "false",
                "VolumeSize": "20"
                }
            }],
            "KeyName": "Testing",
            "Tags": [{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Public Instance"
            }],
            "UserData": { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                "echo 'Downloading PIP'\n",
                "curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py\n",
                "echo 'Executing PIP using Python'\n",
                "python get-pip.py --user\n",
                "echo 'Setting PIP Classpath'\n",
                "echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile\n",
                "echo 'Reloading bash_profile'\n",
                "source ~/.bash_profile\n",
                "echo 'Installing AWS CLI'\n",
                "pip install awscli --upgrade --user\n"
            ]]}}
        }
    }
```

I can see `.bash_profile` file is getting updated properly with `export PATH` at the end, but the installation of `pip` OR `awscli` is not happening (`pip` / `aws` command says command not found). I checked `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and it does not show up any error as such:

```
Jun 29 01:53:09 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + echo 'Downloading PIP'
Jun 29 01:53:09 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading PIP
Jun 29 01:53:09 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Jun 29 01:53:09 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Jun 29 01:53:09 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Jun 29 01:53:34 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0
  0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0
  0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0
   0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0
     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0#015  0
 0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0#015
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--
  0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:13 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:-
-:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:
16 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--
  0:00:18 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 -
-:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0
    0 --:--:--  0:00:22 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:23 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0
    0      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:25 --:--:--
Jun 29 01:53:40 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: 0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:26 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0
  0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:28 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0
   0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0#015  0     0    0
     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:31 --:--:--     0#015100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0  50760      0  0:00:31  0:00:31 --:--:--  363k
Jun 29 01:53:40 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + echo 'Executing PIP using Python'
Jun 29 01:53:40 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Executing PIP using Python
Jun 29 01:53:40 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + python get-pip.py --user
Jun 29 01:53:42 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting pip
Jun 29 01:53:42 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Jun 29 01:53:42 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting setuptools
Jun 29 01:53:43 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading setuptools-36.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (476kB)
Jun 29 01:53:43 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting wheel
Jun 29 01:53:43 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
Jun 29 01:53:43 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Successfully installed pip-9.0.1 setuptools-36.0.1 wheel-0.29.0
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + echo 'Setting PIP Classpath'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Setting PIP Classpath
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + echo 'Reloading bash_profile'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Reloading bash_profile
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + source /root/.bash_profile
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++ '[' -f /root/.bashrc ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++ . /root/.bashrc
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++ alias 'rm=rm -i'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++ alias 'cp=cp -i'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++ alias 'mv=mv -i'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++ . /etc/bashrc
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ shopt -q login_shell
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' 0 -gt 199 ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ umask 022
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ SHELL=/bin/bash
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/256term.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ . /etc/profile.d/256term.sh
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ local256=
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' -n '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' -n '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ unset local256
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ . /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh -c
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ alias 'grep=grep --color=auto'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ alias 'egrep=egrep --color=auto'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ alias 'fgrep=fgrep --color=auto'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ . /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' '!' -t 0 ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ return
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/lang.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ . /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ sourced=0
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' -n en_US.UTF-8 ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ saved_lang=en_US.UTF-8
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' -f /.i18n ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ unset saved_lang
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ unset sourced
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ unset langfile
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/less.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ . /etc/profile.d/less.sh
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ '[' -x /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ export 'LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ LESSOPEN='||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/which2.sh ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ '[' '' ']'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ . /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: +++++ alias 'which=alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ unset i
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++++ unset -f pathmunge
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++ export PATH
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++ export PATH=/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: ++ PATH=/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + echo 'Installing AWS CLI'
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Installing AWS CLI
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: + pip install awscli --upgrade --user
Jun 29 01:53:44 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting awscli
Jun 29 01:53:45 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading awscli-1.11.113-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
Jun 29 01:53:45 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting botocore==1.5.76 (from awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:46 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading botocore-1.5.76-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5MB)
Jun 29 01:53:46 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 (from awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:46 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading rsa-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB)
Jun 29 01:53:46 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9 (from awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading s3transfer-0.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54kB)
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading docutils-0.13.1-py2-none-any.whl (537kB)
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 (from awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 (from awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:47 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz (253kB)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.5.76->awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.5.76->awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading pyasn1-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53kB)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9
->awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading futures-3.1.1-py2-none-any.whl
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.5.76->awscli)
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Building wheels for collected packages: PyYAML
Jun 29 01:53:48 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyYAML: started
Jun 29 01:53:49 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyYAML: finished with status 'done'
Jun 29 01:53:49 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/2c/f7/79/13f3a12cd723892437c0cfbde1230ab4d82947ff7b3839a4fc
Jun 29 01:53:49 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Successfully built PyYAML
Jun 29 01:53:49 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, jmespath, docutils, botocore, pyasn1, rsa, futures, s3transfer
, colorama, PyYAML, awscli
Jun 29 01:53:50 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Successfully installed PyYAML-3.12 awscli-1.11.113 botocore-1.5.76 colorama-0.3.7 docutils-0.13.1 futures-3.1.1 jme
spath-0.9.3 pyasn1-0.2.3 python-dateutil-2.6.0 rsa-3.4.2 s3transfer-0.1.10 six-1.10.0
Jun 29 01:53:51 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: 2017-06-29 01:53:51,092 - templater.py[WARNING]: Cheetah not available as the default renderer for unknown template
, reverting to the basic renderer.
Jun 29 01:53:51 ip-10-0-1-252 cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Thu, 29 Jun 2017 05:53:51 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.
```

Please let me know where lies the issue and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you run `echo $SHELL` when you're logged in to make sure which shell you're using

Comment: Does it work if you run the commands manually? (Boot a new instance, login, change to root via `sudo su -`, then just paste the commands.)

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/bash` , I tried the commands manually in a new instance with same `AMI` and it works fine. Please suggest how to debug and fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AWS CLI** is getting installed successfully, except it only gets installed for root user because cloud-init runs under root. From [pip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html):

> Passing the --user option to python -m pip install will install a package just for the current user, rather than for all users of the system.

I suspect you are trying to run it with ec2-user: if you want ec2-user and all other users to have access to it then remove the `--user` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Raf answer, you could do run command for an user with,

```
su - user -c 'shell command'
```

For your case,

```
su - ec2-user 'pip install awscli --upgrade --user'
```